# check inside method which role @preauthorize has passed for spring controller method

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, roles

i am using @preauthorize for method level security. For my method1, one of the two roles can only satisfy. But inside that method , i need to know which role it has satisfied this time and based on that i need to set the subsequent journey for functional requirement. My problem is like below -

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('Role_1') or hasAnyRole('Role_2')")
    @RequestMapping(value = URL_MAPPING, method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public ModelAndView methodName(HttpSession session,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) {


        //here i need to know which role it has passed to execute the method.
        if (role1 executed) {
            sessionInformation.updateJourneyInfo(updateforrole1);
        }else{
            sessionInformation.updateJourneyInfo(updateforrole2);
        }
```

Can anybody please help on resolving this issue.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `HttpServletRequest` request to your parameter list for the method then use

```
request.isInRole("ROLE_Role_1")
```

Comment: agreed this is the simplest solution, incase still this doesnt makes sense why dont you simply get the authentication object injected in the method parameters